# How to create environment variables on Azure to access Key Vault

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I want to write a Python code to read a secret stored in Azure Key Vault. This code will run on the cloud on an Azure container. It goes like this:

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError
import os


VAULT_URL = os.environ["VAULT_URL"]
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient(vault_url=VAULT_URL, credential=credential)

print("\n.. Get a Secret by name")
company_secret = client.get_secret('secret_name')
print("Secret with name '{0}' was found with value '{1}'.".format(company_secret.name, company_secret.value))
```

The thing is, I should specify some Environment variables like Vault URL and I don't know how to do that. I also don't know where I should put my credentials to actually access the Key Vault.

The main question is: how do I establish environment variables?

Thank you

Comment: The DefaultAzureCredential used in your code will try to get your credentials from different sources, starting with environment variables as described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/README.md#defaultazurecredential). Setting "AZURE_TENANT_ID", "AZURE_CLIENT_ID", and "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET" environment variables will do the job, but you can check the documentation for other ways to authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are just a dict, so setting them is very similar to getting them.

```
# Gets env var
VAULT_URL = os.environ["VAULT_URL"] 
# Sets env var
os.environ['URL_VAULT'] = 'Some value'
```

You may wish to verify they do not exist prior to overwriting:

```
if 'URL_VAULT' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['URL_VAULT'] = 'Some value'
```

Comment: Thank you! One question: if this is the case, what's the difference between using environmental variables and regular variables like doing: vault_url = 'some value'?

Comment: Environment variables can be useful for passing information between distinct processes. Take a web proxy for instance, you'd set it's value on login and then other processes would be able to access it to know where to send http/s requests.